# Batch file '%' put additional space while setting java property

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am running java application using command line and in that i have to inject some system level properties using "-D" flag. The property is are passed as a argument to the batch file and i set it and run the jar file like this.

```
java -Dservice.url="http://localhost:%port%/someservice" -jar program.jar
```

The problem is that %port% puts additional space in the end and its causing issues. Upon printing the property inside the application i found out that it is being set as like this.

service.url=http://localhost:8080 /someservice

ideally it should be like this

service.url=http://localhost:8080/someservice

i have tried removing quotes, adding quotes, many solutions but they are not working.

Comment: show the code where you set the variable `%port%` in other words, show the batch code please.

Comment: Why the space is not before `8080` if `%` is inserting the space?

Comment: Yes. right. in the start of the script a loop is running that is setting different properties. i just checked that set port=something has additional space character present in the end. removing that have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Always wrap your variables in double quotes including the variable name, to ensure no whitespace creep in there:

```
set "port=8080"
```